# how to install macOS high sierra without lose data?

Tags: macos

I need to install macOS high sierra but i need to know the data will be erased or not and what is the way to install it without lose data.

Comment: The one sure way to ensure you don't lose data during an upgrade is to do a backup of your data *before* performing the upgrade.

Comment: Now i don't have any external device to backup data so i asked the question

Comment: Get one.  They are very inexpensive and if something happens, it will be the cheapest insurance policy you will ever buy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does upgrading Yosemite risk losing material on HD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188125/does-upgrading-yosemite-risk-losing-material-on-hd)

Comment: To put this into context, this question was just asked today:  [Update macbook air to High Sierra frozen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331973/update-macbook-air-to-high-sierra-frozen).  ***This is exactly why you need a backup***.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, your can "upgrade in place" meaning High Sierra will install, upgrading your old version of macOS while keeping your data intact.

However, **you should back up your data**.  [This is the very first thing Apple says to do after checking that the upgrade is compatible with your machine.](https://www.apple.com/macos/how-to-upgrade/)

[image: Make Sure You're Ready to Upgrade]

> **Before you upgrade, we recommend that you back up your Mac.** Then, if
>   your Mac is running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8 or later, you can upgrade
>   directly to macOS High Sierra.

Upgrades *should* go without issue, but things happen.  For example, the upgrade could be interrupted for any reason beyond your control thus, compromising your data.

Additionally, High Sierra will convert your HFS+ file system to APFS on the fly meaning you're converting file system that "holds" your data.  This introduces another level of complexity increasing the chance for failure.